# kNN with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm writing a k nearest neighbors implementation to solve multiclass classification.

```
import heapq
import logging

import numpy as np

from scipy import spatial

logging.basicConfig()

class KNN(object):

    similarities = {
        1: lambda a, b: np.linalg.norm(a-b),
        2: lambda a, b: spatial.distance.cosine(a, b),
    }

    def __init__(self, k, similarity_func, loglevel=logging.DEBUG):
        self.k = k
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(type(self).__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(loglevel)
        if similarity_func not in KNN.similarities:
            raise ValueError("Illegal similarity value {0}. Legal values are {1}".format(similarity_func, sorted(KNN.similarities.keys())))
        self.similarity_func = KNN.similarities[similarity_func]

    def train(self, X, y):
        self.training_X = X
        self.training_y = y
        self.num_classes = len(np.unique(y))
        self.logger.debug("There are %s classes", self.num_classes)
        return self

    def probs(self, X):
        class_probs = []
        for i, e in enumerate(X, 1):
            votes = np.zeros((self.num_classes,))
            self.logger.debug("Votes: %s", votes)
            if i % 100 == 0:
                self.logger.info("Example %s", i)
            distance = [(self.similarity_func(e, x), y) for x, y in zip(self.training_X, self.training_y)]
            for (_, label) in heapq.nsmallest(self.k, distance, lambda t: t[0]):
                votes[label] += 1
            class_probs.append(normalize(votes))
        return class_probs

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.argmax(self.probs(X))
```

I find that this implementation's `predict` is slow™ and think it could be sped up with vectorized operations in numpy, but I'm fairly inexperienced with numpy vectorization techniques.

Does anyone have some suggestions for performance boosts I can get from `predict`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post one optimization:

### Euclidean distances don't need to be computed fully!

Because I'm only using them for ranking, a square root is unnecessary. Therefore, the following can be used:

```
def squared_euclidean(x, y):
    dist = np.array(x) - np.array(y)
    return np.dot(dist, dist)
```